# How to Update All Browsers At Once After Sending Data to Server via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently using jQuery's `AJAX` to send and receive data when making a new post. However, when I open two browser tabs of the same website, I notice that the second tabs doesn't update itself after I do something with the first tab.

For example, if I "like" some posts in the first tab, the posts in the first tab will update its "post number" after receiving data from server via `AJAX`, but the second tab still stays the same as if nothing happens, unless I refresh the second tab.

I understand that one of the method is by using HTML5's `WebSocket`. I am just curious if it's possible update all the browser views simultaneously with jQuery's `AJAX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to update second browser tab based on action in first tab. But for listening changes from server you should make use of `WebSockets` to establish connection with server and server will push changes on your connection. [Websocket](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm) is supported in html5 version. other way to do it old way which is long polling where you keep calling server to get updates & hidden frame approach also (you can get more detail on this by googling it). apart form there are other methods also to do this stuff.

I suggest make use of `SignalR` which is provided by Microsoft, it includes all the way to handle requirement of Server to multiple clients. you can check here : [Introduction to SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

[image]